# Which shell /sbin/sh is in hp-unix?

Tags: linux, shell, unix, posix, hp-ux

I am new to hp-unix .I typed the command echo $SHELL and got output as /sbin/sh what shell is it

I googled and found it to be default shell for root user but the name of the shell please

Comment: Not a programming question; nominating to close as off-topic.  Also quick googling brought up https://www.in-ulm.de/~mascheck/various/shells/

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK it's called POSIX Shell.

If you're using an older HP-UX release (less than HP-UX 11i Version 1.5) it is the Bourne shell.